# mysql select last 3 distinct rows but order by asc

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I am trying to select a distinct column from the last 3 rows of a table and then order it ascending.

Any help is appreciated.

The code below gives me the following error:
"Unknown column 'entry_id' in 'order clause'"

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT distinct(column) as sem FROM table ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 3
) sub
ORDER BY entry_id ASC
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Note that distinct is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You need the subquery to return the ordering column, otherwise it is not available in the outer query.

This gets tricky because of the use of `distinct` in the subquery. As commented by Barmar, adding `entry_id` to the `select distinct` clause might break the `distinct`, so we can turn on aggregation instead:

```
SELECT column FROM (
    SELECT column, max(entry_id) max_entry_id as sem 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY max_entry_id DESC LIMIT 3
) sub
ORDER BY max_entry_id
```

Note: `distinct` is not a function, so it does implies parentheses.

Comment: If `entry_id` is a unique ID, this will probably break the `distinct`. It should be `select column, max(entry_id) as entry_id ... group by column`.

Comment: @Barmar: yes you are correct, I was speculating on how to address this... I think that  aggregation should be the proper solution, as you suggested. Answer updated, thank you.

Comment: Rats, I think I wrote my question wrong!  What I need is for the last three distinct rows.  So if one column contains the month and five rows are Feb, 3 rows are March and 2 rows are July...I need to return the last row for each month in the asc order like:
Feb
Mar
Jul